# jquery .ajax() GET request sending OPTIONS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send an ajax request from my localhost development box to a server using

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSSample</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var params = {
            format: "JSON",
            season: "2015REG"
            // Request parameters
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "https://<mysite>/sub/" + params.format + "/" + params.season,
            beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
                // Request headers
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key","<mykey>");
            },
            type: "GET"
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            alert("success");
            console.log("Data: \n" + JSON.stringify(data));
        })
        .fail(function(error) {
            alert("error");
            console.log("Error" + JSON.stringify(error));
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

when I look into firefox i see that it is actually sending an OPTIONS request - which is not responded to by the server (404 not found) , so I then get a Cross-Origin Request blocked error.

```
OPTIONS 
XHR 
https://mysite [HTTP/1.1 404 Resource Not Found 2437ms]
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://mysite (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is jquery trying to ask for options when I am explicitly sending a GET? Also, I don't own this server, its another company, that has a subscription API, so I can't give out the key or anything to help troubleshoot.

Comment: The browser sends the options request, the domain of the page is not the same domain as the one you is reaching with ajax, basically the browser asks the server: ey this domain is reaching you, do I let it. And as you said you is having cors error. The browser is blocking yow request

Answer (score 1):

If the other server is yours, you can enable [cors](https://enable-cors.org/)

Otherwise you cannot (in most cases*) make requests to a foreign domain via `ajax`

> JavaScript and the web programming has grown by leaps and bounds over
> the years, but the same-origin policy still remains. This prevents
> JavaScript from making requests across domain boundaries, and has
> spawned various hacks for making cross-domain requests.
>
> CORS introduces a standard mechanism that can be used by all browsers
> for implementing cross-domain requests. The spec defines a set of
> headers that allow the browser and server to communicate about which
> requests are (and are not) allowed. CORS continues the spirit of the
> open web by bringing API access to all.

---

One way to bypass CORS is using [whateverorigin.org](http://www.whateverorigin.org/), here's an example.

```
 $.getJSON('http://whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent('http://google.com') + '&callback=?', function(data){
    alert(data.contents);
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I was just updating the question to say I didnt own the server. However, I was able to use the Chrome RestClient app to test the request, and it is succesfull using that client. Does this imply that I am doing something wrong in my code?

Comment: [JSONP](http://dev.socrata.com/docs/cors-and-jsonp.html) might be another alternative  - but it would seem that OP is doing something inherently wrong if he's running into this.

Comment: @Derek you may want to update your question with the full code.

Answer (score 1):

Preflight (that's what is happening) for CORS is done when

- request method is not GET, HEAD or POST; **or**
- custom request header is used

In your case, your custom header is triggering the preflight

Effectively, your CORS request is being rejected by the server. From what you've posted, you need a custom header in the request, therefore the remote server needs to handle the preflight requests if it is to offer CORS resources

It's possible the server you are trying to use has not been set up to allow client (browser) connections, only "server" connections which do not have cross origin restrictions

Comment: So any idea why it works when I am using the Chrome app RestClient to test the connection, but not when I just make this simple page and load it on localhost?

Comment: because chrome apps are not web pages, so do not require CORS response headers from the server. Theoretically, you could write a chrom add-on to work as a sort of proxy for your request if you want. Alternatively, use your server to proxy the request for the client

Comment: @Jaromanda X, Just want to thank you for mentioning the custom header...have been chasing this for days, and that comment did the trick.